# 'Area code not set' issue in custom CLI commands in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, exception

I'm getting following error while updating data through `CustomerRepositoryInterface`

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\SessionException]  
Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.

[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]  
Area code is not set
```

Following is my `di.xml` file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="test1_command" xsi:type="object">Test\Module\Console\Command\Test1Command</item>
                <item name="test2_command" xsi:type="object">Test\Module\Console\Command\Test2Command</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Could you please show more of your code and give more context as to what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. However the solution shown above does not work for me. This has been perplexing me for weeks now.

Comment: You can find more information in this https://tagvibe.com//magento2/how-to-fix-the-area-code-not-set-issue/

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The area is not set in Magento CLI (it is not required for any core commands). It can be set at the beginning of your command's `execute` method:

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\State **/
private $state;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\State $state) {
    $this->state = $state;
    parent::__construct();
}

public function execute() {
    $this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND); // or \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML, depending on your needs
}
```

Comment: FYI, you "adminhtml" was not working for me. "admin" worked.

Comment: For me it doesn't work (`admin` or `adminhtml`) - there is an error: `Area code already set`. But then, if I comment it out there is exception from subject again.

Comment: You should use `\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_*` constants instead of hardcoded strings

Comment: For me area code admin and adminhtml didn't work however frontend worked.

Comment: It's best not to set the area code in your constructor; whenever you run `bin/magento` **all** the constructors are executed, and if the area code is tried to be set 2 times an exception is thrown. It's better to set the area code in your `execute()`-method, or run your code in store- or area emulation if state is required. Also: constructor dependencies that could trigger a session down the chain should be initialized using a factory or a proxy to prevent dependencies from setting an area code.

Comment: Please unset it as a correct answer. It creates exception when we set area code in constructor.

Comment: In which file should we add this code? I have exactly the same error.

Comment: The answer has been updated and added to `execute()` method instead of  `__construct()`

But on CLI command it is good to set Global area code instead of Frontend
`$this->appState->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);`

Comment: I would say that correct answer is emulating area code and running function causing exception in emulated area code.

Comment: Please follow this article to know the details which might help you http://tagvibe.com/magento2/how-to-fix-the-area-code-not-set-issue/

Comment: where can I put this code?

Comment: Thanks @rajatkara , your link helped me.I placed the di.xml file inside the adminhtml and used the area code as adminhtml and it worked.

Answer (score 47):

I've stumbled into this problem again today and it's important to know that this problem is thrown whenever a dependency down the chain initiates an instance that needs to know the state of the application.

In many cases this error is session-bound (since the session needs to know the state of the application (frontend or adminhtml)).

In my case I needed to have `Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface` in a CLI command, but this requires at some point in it's dependency chain the customer session (probably to get the customer group).

**Edit:** I found a better solution using proxies. But for histories' sake, here's my previous answer:

---

To solve this I did not include this interface in my constructor, but rather it's factory:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterfaceFactory
 */
protected $taxCalculationFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterfaceFactory $taxCalculationFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterfaceFactory $taxCalculationFactory
) {
    $this->taxCalculationFactory = $taxCalculationFactory;
}
```

This way, the class is only instantiated in the one method where I needed it, and no longer in the constructor:

```
$taxCalculation = $this->taxCalculationFactory->create();
```

This solved the problem for me in this particular case.

---

**And now the answer using a proxy:**

If you don't want to trigger all the dependencies down the chain, you should use a proxy in your constructor. According to the [original documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/proxies.html):

> ... constructor injection also means that a chain reaction of object instantiation is often the result when you create an object.

and:

> ... Proxies extend other classes to become lazy-loaded versions of them. That is, a real instance of the class a proxy extends created only after one of the class’s methods is actually called.

So in my situation, with the `TaxCalculationInterface`, all I had to do was instantiate my tax calculation as a proxy in my constructor:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface\Proxy
 */
protected $taxCalculation;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface\Proxy $taxCalculation
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface\Proxy $taxCalculation
) {
    $this->taxCalculation = $taxCalculation;
}
```

This way, my class is lazy loaded. That is: it's only instantiated as soon as I call one of it's methods. For example:

```
$rate = $this->taxCalculation->getCalculatedRate($productRateId);
```

Comment: this is the correct answer for me. To debug which commands have problems, I comment <item> tags in di.xml for commands definition in my custom modules, and uncommenting every item and compile to test which fails

Answer (score 23):

You shouldn't use `setAreaCode` in the **`__construct`** for CLI commands. When you run any command Magento collect and create instance for each script registered in your application. If there are more than one **`__construct`** with area code definition you will have the error.

I suppose better to use the **`execute()`** method to set area code. Check the catalog module:
`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Console/Command/ImagesResizeCommand.php`

Comment: Makes sense to me. Anyone else wants to add a comment on this?

Comment: This is correct, see also my comment on the accepted answer: It's best not to set the area code in your constructor; whenever you run `bin/magento` **all** the constructors are executed, and if the area code is tried to be set 2 times an exception is thrown. It's better to set the area code in your `execute()`-method, or run your code in store- or area emulation if state is required. Also: constructor dependencies that could trigger a session down the chain should be initialized using a factory or a proxy to prevent dependencies from setting an area code.

Comment: but in Magento 2.2, injecting \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface or \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface in command class constructs will call  Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct() and will end up "area not set". This doesn't happen 2.1. because module-ui/Config/Reader/Definition/Data is introduced in 2.2

how do we solve this?

Answer (score 12):

In most cases exception is caused by some actions performed in console command. Solution (instead of setting area code) is to emulate area code and perform action using

`$this->state->emulateAreaCode(Area::AREA_ADMINHTML, [$this, 'someAction'], []);`

where `$state` is object of `Magento\Framework\App\State`. Setting area in different place is a problem, because it can cause conflict between calls.

Comment: I am using this reference and getting the similar error Area code is already set in my controller, can you please help me to get out of this. I have made changes like, calling setareacode in my construct function but getting same error.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175549/how-to-programmatically-sign-in-to-the-administration-area-from-a-module

Answer (score 7):

In **magento 2** if you set **AreaCode** but still get this error then please try following code.

- Use `Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;`
- include `app/bootstrap.php;`
- $bootstrap = `Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);`
- $objectManager = `$bootstrap->getObjectManager();`
- $state = `$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');`
- $state->setAreaCode('global');

Answer (score 6):

for this areaCode issue, if the 'frontend' parameter is not working, try  :

```
$this->_state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);
```

was working for me, hope it helps

Comment: In which file should I add this code? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @xxx I had this problem from a custom command, so I wrote this in the command file I created. You can add it in the execute function, with something like : `try { $this->_state->... } finally { $this->executeMyCommand() }`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that it does not have any method that returns false if the variable area_code has not been set.
The way I found it to solve was by creating override of the state class and creating a new method to validate if the area_code was set.

In my file di.xml

```
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\App\State" type="Webjump\Abacos\App\State" />
```

Createad file Webjump\Abacos\App\State

```
namespace Webjump\Abacos\App;

class State extends \Magento\Framework\App\State
{
    public function validateAreaCode()
    {
        if (!isset($this->_areaCode)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Use

```
/**
* @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
*/
protected $state;

public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
)
{
$this->state = $state;
if (!$this->state->validateAreaCode()) {
 $this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
}
}
```

Comment: I think it's easier to wrap the setAreaCode() call in a try/catch block

Answer (score 6):

Try to upgrade magento using CLI than i found 'area code not define' for session & app.But i can't find which module or theme.so i just do below changes in `vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php` file & it's working.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Config\ScopeInterface $configScope,
    $mode = self::MODE_DEFAULT
) {
    $this->_areaCode = Area::AREA_GLOBAL;
    $this->_configScope = $configScope;
    switch ($mode) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It's just temporary solution for ignore error you must find out module for that.

Answer (score 2):

I have found same issue with Area code while setup upgrade.

```
Module 'Magento_WebsiteRestriction':Installing data... Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session
```

I have disabled all third party modules and run `setup:upgrade`

Then I have re-enabled all of third party modules and run same command.
 Problem is solved for me
 Hope this is help for you.

Comment: this is not actually a solution. It's just hiding the dirt under the rug. But good find anyway. It should help during the development process, but it does not make the problem go away.

Comment: Thank you Marius for correcting me. I have find  the same case in most of my project and this help me to resolve this.

Comment: @Marius, would you care to explain why, and let people know the most canonical method to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution by using the proxy class. Example is

```
use Klevu\Search\Model\Product\MagentoProductActionsInterface\Proxy as MagentoProductActionsInterface;

public function __construct(
        MagentoProductActionsInterface $magentoProductActionsInterface
    )
    {
        $this->_magentoProductActionsInterface = $magentoProductActionsInterface;
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

This fixed my issue

Answer (score 2):

Some of my research on this issue indicates that where the console command is declared plays a factor into WHY an area code needs to be defined.  If the command is declared in a modules `etc/di.xml` file, Magento doesn't know what area it is intended for and thus a line like `$this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);` is required.  However if the command was declared in `etc/adminhtml/di.xml` the `setAreaCode()` could be skipped as `di.xml` specified the area.

One other thing that tripped me up for a while was that I was trying to use `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface` in the `__construct` to be able to load an order.  This caused the `Area code is not set` error.  I changed it to `\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository` and had success.  Moral of the story is that some dependencies may have issues with the command scripts for the area for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I was suffering of error 'Area code is not set' running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` after import database from production.
It's a little bit different case than this topic subject, but maybe will help someone.
I was able to resolve this issue locally running `bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` despite I already was in developer mode.
Magento did some configuration adjustments, specially for me debug_logging played role.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the area in the command files didn't fix it for me!
What did is moving the di.xml where the commands are declared into adminhtml folder(or in frontend if thats what's needed)!