# Magento 2 Custom command Area Code note set exception

Tags: magento2, import, command-line

I have created a command for my module which calls a class Model/Importer from https://github.com/firegento/FireGento_FastSimpleImport2 extension. but i think it requires admin session.

I have tried to add area code by referring  to this  question ['Area code not set' issue in custom CLI commands in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96747/area-code-not-set-issue-in-custom-cli-commands-in-magento-2)

But still after clearing everything from `var` folder, i am getting the same exception.

Comment: http://tagvibe.com/magento2/how-to-fix-the-area-code-not-set-issue/ Check this URL to fix the area code exception in Magento 2

Answer (score 3):

```
#File: vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php
```

If you debug the above file,`Magento\Framework\App\State` object will only let you set a value once. As you know a command line scripts has no area.

Below code should pass the Area code not set exceptions.

When I was trying for the same, I did get the below working code from somewhere. It was working for me few days ago.

```
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState,
    $name=null
)
{
    $appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
    parent::__construct($name);
}
```