# Move Magento 2 Area code is not set problem

Tags: magento2, cache, transfer

I am trying to move magento 2 to another server but when I am trying to flush cache I am getting this error:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush

[Magento\Framework\Exception\SessionException]
Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.

[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
Area code is not set

cache:flush [--bootstrap="..."] [types1] ... [typesN]
```

I already updated database with the new directory.

What should I do ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96747/area-code-not-set-issue-in-custom-cli-commands-in-magento-2