# Area Code not set when Model is used while using Upgrade Data Script

Tags: model, code, upgrade-script, setup-upgrade, area

I have following code in **UpgradeData.php**

```
protected $test;

public function __construct(
        \Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Test $test
    )
    {
        $this->test = $test;
    }

public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
....
        $this->test->install();
....
}
```

I have following code in **Test.php**

> Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Test.php

```
class Test
{
protected $testmodel;

public function __construct(
        \Vendor\ModuleName\Model\TestModel $testmodel
    )
    {
        $this->testmodel = $testmodel;
    }
}

public function install(){
....
$result = $this->testmodel->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('testcol','abcd')->getFirstItem();
....
}
```

Now, when I run

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

I get following error

[image]

When I remove TestModel class from constructor and its usage from install function, the upgrade script runs successfully.

I even tried to use solution mentioned in below link but none of them worked

['Area code not set' issue in custom CLI commands in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96747/area-code-not-set-issue-in-custom-cli-commands-in-magento-2)

I'm trying to fetch as well as insert data into database.

Edit #1 :

I even tried to use **\Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\TestModel\CollectionFactory** instead of **\Vendor\ModuleName\Model\TestModel** in my Test.php and when I run following command

```
$result = $this->testmodel->create();
```

It doesn't give any error on **setup:upgrade** command,
but as soon as I try to use **addFieldToFilter** it gives the same error