# Magento 2 CLI Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session

Tags: magento2, exception, cli

When I use one of the following commands,

```
php bin/magento module:status
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento module:enable <module_name>
```

I'll get an error

```
 [Magento\Framework\Exception\SessionException]                       
  Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.
```

And if I add -vvv option to the command, I'll get the below Exception trace, but I'm not able to find out which file cause the error. Can someone please help?

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\SessionException]                       
Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.




Exception trace:
 () at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:175
 Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start() at /www/magento2/public/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php:50
 Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->start() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:130
 Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct() at /www/magento2/public/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php:14
 Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->__construct() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:144
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:230
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:144
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:230
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:144
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:230
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:144
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:230
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:144
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:230
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:144
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:230
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:144
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:230
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:180
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:156
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:230
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:137
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getApplicationCommands() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:118
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getDefaultCommands() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1147
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->init() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:503
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:190
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:104
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /www/magento2/public/bin/magento:23


  [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]  
  Area code is not set                              


Exception trace:
 () at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php:152
 Magento\Framework\App\State->getAreaCode() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:173
 Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->start() at /www/magento2/public/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php:50
 Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->start() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:130
 Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager->__construct() at /www/magento2/public/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Session/Generic/Interceptor.php:14
 Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor->__construct() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:144
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:230
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:144
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:230
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:144
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:230
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:144
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:230
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:144
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:230
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:144
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:230
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:144
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:230
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:180
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:156
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:230
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:34
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:59
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56
 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:137
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getApplicationCommands() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:118
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getDefaultCommands() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1147
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->init() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:503
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:190
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:104
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /www/magento2/public/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /www/magento2/public/bin/magento:23
```

Comment: Plese Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96747/area-code-not-set-issue-in-custom-cli-commands-in-magento-2

Comment: They suggested to add  $state->setAreaCode('frontend');  in the constructor, but I'm not sure in which file should I add this.

Comment: Here is the path `root folder\vendor\magento\framework\App\State.php`

Comment: My website crashed when I add setAreaCode to the State.php. I'll check  if I did anything wrong, and give you an update. thanks.

Comment: @MagentoLearner Can you please let me know have you resolved your problem? As I have this issue produced after installing a third party module.